# Error when installing px-data-table bower component

Tags: predix

When I try to `bower install --save px-data-table` in my Angular 2 app, I get the following error:

```
bower ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for webcomponentsjs
```

Unaware how to fix this, considering I do not have webcomponentsjs installed (I checked both my `package.json` and my `bower.json`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how bower works for all components, not specific to Predix.  Sounds like your application has one component that depends on version X of webcomponentsjs, and another component that depends on version Y of webcomponentsjs.  If you run `bower install` manually, you should see the components with conflicts.  Then you can modify or lock in versions of those components.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like running the command with the `--force-latest` flag fixed the issue for me. Full command: `bower install --force-latest --save px-data-table`.

Still looking for clarification here if anyone can explain why bower was not looking for the latest version by default.